# Inside and outside of an ellipsoid

Tags: conic-sections, positive-definite

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix.

The equation $x^TAx=1$ defines an ellipsoid.

I would like to justify the fact that $x^T A x > 1$ implies that $x$ is outside of the ellispoid.

In other words, why is $\{x\ | \ x^TAx\leq1\}$ the "full" ellipsoid?

Comment: Can you prove this when $A$ is a multiple of the identity matrix, and thus defines a sphere? The general case can be obtained from this by an affine transformation.

Answer (score 2):

The ellipsoid is the surface such that $x^TAx-1$ is zero, and by continuity this expression cannot change sign without $x$ crossing the surface. As the surface is closed, it has an inside and an outside. As it contains the origin, the inside is where $x^TAx-1$ is negative.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What theorem do you use to say that the sign is constant inside/ouside the surface?

Comment: @tiintin: as said, by continuity the sign cannot change without crossing the surface.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to note that $x^\top A x = c^2$ defines an ellipsoid for any $c$.
When $c = 0$, this is a single point $\{0\}$, and as $c^2$ grows, the ellipsoid grows and grows.

---

Alternatively, another way to see this is that if $x^\top A x = c^2 > 1$ then $x/|c|$ lies on the original ellipsoid since $(x/|c|)^\top A (x / |c|) = 1$. But $x/|c|$ is closer to zero than $x$.